# MyPy throws "Incompatible types in assignment" error for dictionaries

Tags: python, mypy

```
def format_response(vehicle_type: str, modifications: list = None) -> dict:

    response = {
        'vehicle_type': vehicle_type,
    }

    if modifications:
        response['modifications'] = modifications

    return response
```

I have a simple function that generates a dict which is then returned eventually as a json response.

MyPy is throwing an error saying:

`error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[Any]", target has type "str")`

Nowhere do I define the dict as being 'str': 'str'.

How do I get around this?

The dictionary format should be either:

```
{
    "vehicle_type": "truck"
}
```

if there is no modifications or else:

```
{
    "vehicle_type": "truck",
    "modifications": [{'engine_upgrade':'2.5'},{'colour_change':'red'}]

}
```

On a related note if there is a dictionary that is string: string but I use a return value from a function as a lookup key that is an optional string. There is a mypy error

`Invalid index type "Optional[str]" for "Dict[str, str]"; expected type "str"`

However the lookup is wrapped in a `try except` so there is no problem here.

Comment: Explicitly type it as `response: Dict[str, Any] = ...`…?

Comment: I probably could. I just don't like having to throw in more code to get mypy to pass when the code itself is functional. Is it possible to do it in the return type?

Comment: Have one more related question in the question now just in case you know the solution.